# Prorated allocation of resources

Tags: r

Each month a certain number of resources are made available.

There's a defined 'usage' rate from months 0 to month n

For ex, in the month of release, 10% of resources are used, 12% additionally in second month, & 15% additionally in third month, so on & so forth until the maximum available resources are used.

**required:**:

How many resources are used each month.

**for example,**

1. in month 1, there are 10% of the resources released in month 1
2. in month 2, there are 12% of resources released in month 1 + 10% of resources released in month 2
3. in month 3, there are 15% of resources released in month 1 + 12 % of resources released in month 2 + 10% of resources released in month 3
   & so on..

The logic is implemented in Excel thus:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/752098-array-formula-allocate-revenues-across-periods.html

How can I implement this in R?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome. That's a well-asked Q. SO philosophy requires askers to show their work so far and to ask for help with specific problem they're facing.

Comment: as a side comment I would add that the title is probably a little confusing (I thought it was about memory allocation).

Comment: thanks @MikeC, i'm finding that getting the question right is much harder than I thought :)

Comment: @VincentBonhomme - i'm struggling with defining this, any suggestions welcome.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `cumsum()`

```
> used<-c(0.1,0.12,0.15)
> cumsum(used)
[1] 0.10 0.22 0.37
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks @Jen. `cumsum()` unfortunately doesn't do the trick in this instance.

Comment: Hi @Neil, could you explain why this isn't giving you what you need? Maybe you can give an example with input values and expected output to help understand what you are trying to do?